# Hibernate fetch strategy for associations

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
public class A {

 @Id
 private Long id;

 @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
 @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
 private List<B> bList;

}

@Entity
public class B {

 @Id
 private Long id;

 private Long aId;

 @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "bId")
 @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
 private List<C> cList;

}

@Entity
public class C {

 @Id
 private Long id;

 private Long bId;

}
```

When loading object of type A (session.get(A.class, 1L)) the join fechmode specified for list of C objects in B is ignored. 3 queries are executed:
select A ...
select B ...
select C ...

When loading objects of type B (session.get(B.class, 1L)) the join fetchmode is honored and only 1 query is executed

select B ...
    left outer join C ...

What i want is when loading object of type A that only 2 queries are needed:
select A ...
select B ...
    left outer join C ...

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: What will happend when you will set `FetchMode.JOIN` for `B` as well?

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tried your example and there are two selects.

Comment: @Antoniossss FethMode.JOIN for B results in one query. But the problem for that is that on my project, the query becomes too big and too slow.

Comment: @Petar Must be some hibernate setting then, I can't seem to force 2 queries.

Comment: How you fetching A object? Do you using Query maybe(HQL)?

Comment: No, session.get(A.class, 1L)   The real scenario is a bit more complex that that may be the cause of the problem... the collection  of C is not defined in B itself but in a MappedSuperclass B'  maybe that's the cause of the problem...